# I/O redirection using cygwin and mingw

Tags: bash, cygwin, redirection, io, mingw

I have written a program in C and have compiled it using MinGW.  When I try to run that program in Cygwin, it seems to behave normally (i.e. prints correct output etc.)

However, I'm trying to pipe output to a program so that I can parse information from the program's output.  However, the piping does not seem to be working in that I am not getting any input into the second program.

I have confirmed this by using the following commands:

This command seems to work fine:

```
./prog
```

Performing this command returns nothing:

```
./prog | cat
```

This command verifies the first:

```
./prog | wc
```

Which returns:

```
0 0 0
```

I know that the script (including the piping from the program) works perfectly fine in an all Linux environment.

Does anyone have any idea for why the piping isn't working in Cygwin?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour piping it to `more` or redirecting `stdout` to an actual file?

Comment: @Breakthrough Yes.  Outputting to a file "./prog &> output.txt" or "./prog > output.txt" yields an empty output.txt

Comment: a few questions: are you printing to stdout? are you printing the right end of line character for windows (\r\n)?

Comment: @Pablo Castellazzi I am printing to stdout (just using printf), but am using "\n" instead of "\r\n."  I don't think that should change the fact that I'm not getting any output at al, right?  I will try changing the line endings to \r\n and let you know.

Comment: I just wrote a little C app that uses printf and was able to pipe to wc and less and such.  What version of cygwin are you running?

Comment: You should link your source code

Comment: The program may be opening `/dev/tty` and writing to that.  That's the only explaination I can think of for this behavior.

Comment: I believe the problem was that I was not flushing the output stream `fflush(stdout)` in my application, which caused the data not to be output to the file, but output to the screen properly (\n line breaks).

Comment: The flushing would explain it.  When writting to a pipe, stdout is block buffered (e.g., 4096-bytes at a time, so the first block isn't written until the 4097th byte is written), but when writing to a terminal, stdout is line buffered (i.e., each newline flushes the buffers).

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45805785/880783

Answer (score 3):

Most probably this has to do with stdio buffering, as identified and explained previously in the comments section. In my MinGW projects, I have often used the following construct:

```
#define disable_stdout_buffering() do { \
               setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); } while(0)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    disable_stdout_buffering();
    /* Your code */
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Of course you can also add a call to `fflush()` in a preprocessor macro or when you output your data to stdout, however this way it does not add an additional library call to each buffer written to your console.